# Не конфиденциально слитно или раздельно

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные

Как написать:

**Без приложения - не конфиденциально.**

или

**Без приложения неконфиденциально.**

Имеется в виду то, что создан документ, содержащий конфиденциальную информацию. А в сопроводительном письме о направлении этого документа конфиденциальной информации нет. Вот и пишем в письме: Без приложения - не конфиденциально.

Я бы вот и тире поставила, и раздельно написала.
К какой части речи отнести слово *конфиденциально* в данном контексте?

Comment: @Анна Филатова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что конкретно для "конфиденциальный" и "конфиденциально" по причинам стилистического характера не следует образовывать слов со встроенным отрицанием: неестественно приписывать чему-либо свойство, противоположное исключительности. "Конфиденциально" означает "доверительно в отношении конкретных лиц" (обычно, адресата), это не прямой синоним слова "секретно" (для ограниченного круга неопределённых лиц), от которого можно образовать слово "несекретный" (здесь естественно деление на секретное и несекретное).

Если поискать гуглом слово "неконфиденциальный", можно убедиться, что оно практически не употребляется - вместо него вы увидите "конфиденциальный". А раз по отношению к "конфиденциальности" не принято говорить с "утверждением отрицания", то и выбора нет: можно только отрицать само "позитивно" выраженное свойство - отдельной частицей. "Это не конфиденциально" (= нет причин от посторонних скрывать), "это (вам) не конфиденциальный разговор, можете всем рассказать" (отрицание относится к "разговору" с обозначенным свойством, а не к прилагательному - нет такого прилагательного с отрицанием). По этим причинам исходное выражение (в любом написании) не воспринимается как "гриф", и лучше написать конкретно: "без приложения документ не содержит конфиденциальной информации".

Answer (score 1):

Документ содержит конфиденциальную информацию. 
В сопроводительное письме о направлении этого документа конфиденциальной информации нет.
Тогда так и следует: Приложение - конфиденциально.
Но если следовать предложенной форме, я написал бы: Без приложения - неконфиденциально.
Либо: Без приложения неконфиденциально. Первое - более строго, официально, формально.
Раздельно "не" следует писать в случае, если далее следовало бы противопоставление. 
Вариант. Без приложения [данное письмо] не конфиденциально, а напротив, должно быть доведено до сведения присутствующих.

Answer (score 0):

Если напишете раздельно, ошибкой точно не будет.

**P.S.**

А часть речи -- краткое прилагательное.

Answer (score 0):

[@Alex_ander](/users/4309/alex_ander) прав. Вряд ли есть такое слово – *неконфиденциально*.

Comment: Спасибо всем за участие. Только у нас в головной организации придумали такой гриф.
Конфиденциально.
Наименование организации.
Адрес организации.
Экз.#1.
Без приложения неконфиденциально.

Именно так. Ещё и в инструкцию по ведению конфиденциального делопроизводства это закрепили. Поэтому в формулировке ничего менять не могу. Могу только грамотно это написать, и доказать, что у меня грамотно, а не у них.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается противопоставления, так сама эта фраза противопоставляется первой фразе в грифе. Порывшись в справочниках, выяснила, что слитность или раздельность зависит в данном случае от смысла, контекста. 
Если мы утверждаем отрицание слитно.
Если мы отрицаем утверждение раздельно.
Здесь,как мне кажется, отрицается конфиденциальность, потому я пишу раздельно.
Как кто считает?